# Selenium : WaitForElement (Python) : no differing elements to poll

Tags: python, selenium

so I'm running through paginated data... clicking [Next] and then WaitForElement-ing as it's AJAX-driven.

However, there are no DIFFERING elements... How can I WaitForElement if it returns true immediately? How can I be sure the AJAX has loaded?

For example, in the case below, what can I do if className elements are present on EVERY AJAX-loaded page?

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text('[Next]').click()
wait.until(lambda b: b.find_elements_by_class_name('className'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are.  I guarantee you there's at least one different element in the new page, because otherwise the pagination mechanism won't know which page to display when you click on PREVIOUS or NEXT.  Keep looking, there will be something like an "*n* of *m* results", an `<a href="/blah.blah.blah?page=n">Next</a>`, or at least an `<input type="hidden" name="nextItem" value="n">`.  These sorts of controls depend on there being client-side state that drives the pagination, and it's always kept inside the page.

Comment: Unless the client-side state is kept in a server-side cookie... Right? At the very least the actual content of the page should change. So perhaps comparing the content of the page could be used as an indicator as well... I agree with your answer anyway though, highly unlikely nothing significant (like page number) changes.

Comment: Nobody in their right mind uses cookies for per-window state information, like paging.  I stand by my assertion - there's something variable in the page to look for.